# PS/2 interface with a mouse

Tags: ps2

I am trying to interface an old PS/2 mouse with a PIC microcontroller but I don't know how exactly the protocol works. Does it work exactly like the keyboard protocol, thus sending to the host 11 bit data packets each containing 1 byte of data? I know the mouse sends 3 data packets each time it detects a movement or click, but does that mean it sends 3 11-bit-packets each time or just a single 27 data packet (1 for start , 8+8+8 for data, a parity bit, end bit)

Comment: Deleted answer because I would agree that it was more commentary... Anyways, Microchip has an application design (and fair warning, this link starts a download for the document). The document talks about hardware design, timing, data transfer, message frames, etc: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/91055c.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The mouse sends each byte separately with the said 11-bit start/parity/stop sequence. It does not combine the bytes into a packet.

But before the mouse sends anything to you, you must send a command to the mouse which makes the mouse to start reporting data back to you.